# Is it a good idea to allow users to send SQLce databases via e-mail?

Tags: winforms, sql-server-ce, smartclient

I have a Winforms app which is being deployed to the employees as a smart-client application. It uses a SQL Server Compact database to store data. I need to add a feature to the app which will allow user to export a particular part of his data to a file and send it via e-mail to his colleague. The other user should be able to import the data, make some changes a send it back. I'm in the process of making a decision which way to go here.
I'm thinking of letting them export SQLce databases (*.sdf) with only the single record. It may be safer to send binary and password protected data and pretty easier to implement as well. Do you think it is a good idea or should I stick with more common solutions - e.g. use XML to export and import the data? Am I missing something important if I'll go with sending the *.sdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea to me! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/01/15/msdn-webcast-introducing-sql-server-compact-3-5.aspx (Using SQL CE as a custom doc format)